# How to hide text under div and table row by java script

Tags: javascript

is this possible to hide text under div or table row by JS code

here is the code -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div row class col-sm-4")
            .each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("div") == "Eligibility Name:") {
                    $(this).parent().hide();
                }
            });    
    });
</script>
```

And HTML is

```
<div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-4">Eligibility Name:</div> 
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="domainfield[0][3]" value="" size="20" class="form-control input-250"></div> </div>
```

but its not working, please suggest.

Comment: Show us your html please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your html

you shouldn't use attr, all you need to do is get the text of Div

```
if ($(this).text() == "Eligibility Name:") {
```

Comment: You Rock, You just made my day :)

Comment: tell me if i want to hide multiple rows

Comment: Got it, multiple if.  Thanks

Comment: @BagfulInternational My pleasure to help.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is not correct, you need like this `$("div .row .col-sm-4")`,use `.` to declare class and `#` to declare id

Comment: ```<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.row .col-sm-4")
            .each(function() {
                if ($(this).text() == "Eligibility Name:") {
                    $(this).parent().hide();
                }
            });    
    });
</script>```                                                                                                  
 use `$(this).text()` to replace`$(this).attr('div')`.